# producing a word from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which is `name=noazet difficulty=easy` and I want to produce the two words `noazet` and `easy`. How can I do this in JavaScript?

I tried `var s = word.split("=");`
but it doesn't give me what I want .

Comment: split on the space first and then split again on `=`

Comment: `"name=noazet difficulty=easy".split(/=|\s/g)` will also do it. Did you try anything more than just `word.split("=")`?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can do it with that split:

```
var s = "name=noazet difficulty=easy";
var arr = s.split('=');
var name = arr[0]; //= "name"
var easy = arr[2]; //= "easy"
```

here, `s.split('=')` returns an array:

```
["name","noazet difficulty","easy"]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code:

```
word.split(' ').map(function(part){return part.split('=')[1];});
```

it will return an array of two elements, first of which is name ("noazet") and second is difficulty ("easy"):

```
["noazet", "easy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

word.split("=") will give you an array of strings which are created by cutting the input along the "=" character, in your case:

```
results = [name,noazet,difficulty,easy]
```

if you want to access noazet and easy, these are indices  1 and 3, ie.

```
results[1] //which is "noazet"
```

(EDIT: if you have a space in your input, as it just appeared in your edit, then you need to split by an empty string first - " ")

Based on your data structure, I'd expect the desired data to be always available in the odd numbered indices - but first of all I'd advise using a different data representation. Where is this string word coming from, user input?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside, a better idea than making an array out of your input might be to map it into an object. For example:

```
var s = "name=noazet difficulty=easy";

var obj = s.split(" ").reduce(function(c,n) {
    var a = n.split("=");
    c[a[0]] = a[1];
    return c;
}, {});
```

This will give you an object that looks like this:

```
{
    name: "noazert",
    difficulty: "easy"
}
```

Which makes getting the right values really easy:

```
var difficulty = obj.difficulty;   // or obj["difficulty"];
```

And this is more robust since you don't need to hard code array indexes or worry about what happens if you set an input string where the keys are reversed, for example:

```
var s = "difficulty=easy name=noazet";
```

Will produce an equivalent object, but would break your code if you hard coded array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**You may be able to get away with splitting it twice: first on spaces, then on equals signs**. This would be one way to do that:

```
function parsePairs(s) {
    return s.split(' ').reduce(
        function (dict, pair) {
            var parts = pair.split('=');
            dict[parts[0]] = parts.slice(1).join('=');
            return dict;
        },
        {}
    );
}
```

This gets you an object with keys equal to the first part of each pair (before the =), and values equal to the second part of each pair (after the =). If a string has multiple equal signs, only the first one is used to obtain the key; the rest become part of the value. For your example, it returns `{"name":"noazet", "difficulty":"hard"}`. From there, getting the values is easy.

The magic happens in the `Array.prototype.reduce` callback. We've used `String.prototype.split` to get each name=value pair already, so we split that on equal signs. The first string from the split becomes the key, and then we join the rest of the parts with an = sign. That way, everything after the first = gets included in the value; if we didn't do that, then an = in the value would get cut off, as would everything after it.

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you may have to polyfill `Array.prototype.reduce`, but polyfills for that are everywhere.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Array.prototype.map() always returns an Array, so it can't exactly reproduce my solution. The closest you could get would be something like `[["name", "noazet"], ["difficulty", "easy"]]`. That's certainly usable, but it's a bit more clumsy, and most devs would probably wind up translating it into something like `{ "name" : "noazet", "difficulty" : "easy" }` anyway. Using `Array.prototype.reduce()` cuts out the intermediate steps.